# Problem with Word Search Generator with python

Tags: python, arrays, search, generator, cpu-word

I am trying to implement some code that runs a search game generator with some words on an array, so I decided to use some code that was tested in a video, in the video seems to be running normaly, however when I run the code it freezes,so  I would like to know what's happening:

This is the code I am talking about:

```
import random
import string

words = ['PYTHON', 'ROBBIE', 'GITHUB', 'BEEF']
grid_size=15
grid = [['_' for _ in range(grid_size)] for _ in range(grid_size)]
orientations = ['leftright','updown','diagonalup','diagonaldown']
#Prints the grid
def print_grid():
    for x in range(grid_size):
        print('\t'*5+' '.join(grid[x]))
#Generates grid
def generategrid(words):
    for word in words:
        word_length = len(word)
        placed = False
        while not placed:
            orientation = random.choice(orientations)
            #Sets orientation given by a random number
            if orientation == 'leftright':
                step_x=1
                step_y=0
            if orientation == 'updown':
                step_x = 0
                step_y = 1
            if orientation == 'diagonalup':
                step_x = 1
                step_y = 1
            if orientation == 'diagonaldown':
                step_x = 1
                step_y = -1
        #We generate a random starting point, then we calculate the ending point and if it exceeds the limit, we calculate the number again
        x_position = random.randint(0,grid_size)
        y_position = random.randint(0,grid_size)
        ending_x = x_position + word_length*step_x
        ending_y = y_position + word_length*step_y
        if ending_x < 0 or ending_x >= grid_size: continue
        if ending_y < 0 or ending_y >= grid_size: continue
        failed=False
        #we set the word on the previously given position
        for i in range(word_length):
            character = word[i]
            new_position_x = x_position + i*step_x
            new_position_y = y_position + i*step_y
            character_at_new_position = grid[new_position_x][new_position_y]
            #if there is some character that could be used to form the word
            if character_at_new_position != '_':
                if character_at_new_position == character:
                        continue
                else:
                        failed = True
                        break      
        if failed:#We do the process from above again until we can put the word on the grid 
            continue
        else:
            #Everything worked perfectly and the word was placed without problems
            for i in range(word_length):
                character = word[i]
                new_position_x = x_position + i*step_x
                new_position_y = y_position + i*step_y
            grid[new_position_x][new_position_y] = character
            placed = True
generategrid(words)
print_grid()
```

When I run the program it freezes, however on the video this code seems to work perfectly. Any advice or observation will be appreciated!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an infinite loop after `while not placed:`. I'm not fully sure what the intention of the code is, but I think you mean to set `placed = True` after a certain amount of time.

Further down in the code it does exactly that, so my guess would be an indentation error. In Python the indentation is what defines the scope for a loop, so double check the indentation in the example that you are looking at.

Comment: Well, it was that, the `placed = True` was inside the for and therefore wasn't reachable for the while, I also dicsovered that because of my laziness i _copy and paste_'d some code that calculates the final position. Btw, this code generates a word seach game given an array, for example, in this case one posible output would be: https://imgur.com/a/SobI38C , I'm kinda new on python so that's a detail that would be common on newbies like me.

Comment: Oh hey, that looks pretty cool! Copying and pasting in Python is a real gotcha, since you can end up copying tabs instead of spaces, and the language won't run the code if they're combined. I'm not sure what editor you are using, but many have a feature to convert tabs to spaces and spaces to tabs. Only semi-relevant but thought it would be helpful if you didn't already know.